# How to compute "doubling time" of discrete time series using Pandas or Numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here's a data set. Each row is a time slice. The first column is a reading. The second one is how many time slices ago the reading was 50% of what it is. I calculated it by hand by eyeballing it so the numbers aren't exactly correct.

```
197 
218 
256 
328     4
413     4
525     4
646     4
777     5
1159    4
1838    2
2417    2
3240    2.5
4257    3
4955    4
5752    5.5
6620    5
7738    5.5
8966    4.5
10402   5
```

So, assume I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [197,218,256,328,413,525,646,777,1159,1838,2417,3240,4257,4955,5752,6620,7738,8966,10402]})
```

How would I compute df.doubling? I can sort of imagine starting at the end and working backwards, each time scanning for a value 50% of my starting value. But there's a better way. I think it has to do with Log2 but not sure how to do it!

Comment: Do you need the exact time slice? Maybe it would be easier to fit some line x = f(t), then compute from that. With your current solution you could run into the problem of 2 or more time slices holding the 50% value.

Comment: I don't think I can assume much of a pattern. So the line fit might be some high degree. If 2 or more time slices hold the 50% value, then I would take the earliest one. So if data was 50, 50, 50, 100 then the doubling times would be _,_,_,4. See I know how to do it by hand, but not sure about the algorithm...

Comment: If you are open to doing it outside of pandas I think it would be pretty easy. Loop through your array, then loop from start to current index looking for the 50% value. Can't think of a way to do it pandas unfortunately.

Comment: I was trying something similar few days ago but could not find a nice solution, I was focusing on interpolation. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#univariate-interpolation  It works fine, but the problem is if two consecutive values are the same. This would have to be handled by hand. For the solution with log2 there is probably a fit required, as mentioned above.

Comment: I think I got a solution, just a sec.

Comment: I added an image with synthetic exponential data to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you working on Covid-19 infections doubling time?

**Please check the results carefully.**

I forgot you are using Pandas, so you might need this first:

```
y = df['val'].to_numpy()
```

This is a first shot:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

y = np.array([197, 218, 256, 328, 413,525, 646, 646, 777,
              1159, 1838, 2417, 3240, 4257, 4955, 4955,
              5752, 6620, 7738, 8966, 10402],
              dtype=float)

# get the deltas to check if there was no increase
# between two consecutive data points        
dy = np.diff(y)

# these are the places without increase
idx = np.argwhere(dy) #could also be np.where(dy == 0.0)[0]

y_fixed = y.copy()

# create the x axis, probably days 
x = np.arange(y.shape[0])

# Hack: increase the second identical value be a
# small amount so the interpolation works
# increase the indices by one to increment the second value
y_fixed[idx + 1] += 0.001

# you need scipy > 0.17 for extrapolation to work
f = interp1d(y_fixed, x, fill_value="extrapolate")

# there are the values you need?
y_half = y / 2.0

# get the according x values by interpolation
x_interp = f(y_half)

# delta between the current day and the date when
# the value was half
dbl = x - x_interp

# this already looks quite good, but double check!
print(dbl)
```

Maybe the x axis needs to be shifted. Or maybe it is correct after all.
I will think about this tomorrow with a fresh brain.

[image]

The next image shows both algorithms with a calculated exponentional data, where two positions where set to non-increasing values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone. Here's the final result: https://pitosalas.github.io/covid/

Comment: I like it. But I like the doubling time going up even more :)

Answer (score 0):

@Joe yes, I am working with that data. Here's an old-school solution. I traced your solution and couldn't quite follow it. But mine is not so elegant, but I **think** it's correct... And the graph looks pretty similar to yours ...!

```
import numpy as np
readings = np.array([197, 218, 256, 328, 413,525, 646, 646, 777,
          1159, 1838, 2417, 3240, 4257, 4955, 4955,
          5752, 6620, 7738, 8966, 10402],
          dtype=float)   

readingsLength = len(readings)
double = np.zeros(readingsLength)
for i in range( readingsLength - 1, -1, -1):
    target = readings[i]
    count = 0
    for j in range(i, -1, -1):
        diffsofar = target-readings[j]
        exact = target / 2
        if diffsofar  > exact:
            f = (exact - readings[j]) / (readings[j]-readings[j+1]) + count
            double[i] = f
            break
        else:
            count = count+1
print(double)
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, the graphs look quite different, I will plot them together with your approach. Let see. You are also using linear interpolation with the line equation, right?

Comment: No, I was wrong, the results are quite similar. There is one deviation in the middle and your approach seems to handle beginning and end differently. See the updated picture in my answer.

Comment: The deviations might be the spots with no increase that I added to the data.

Comment: Also I chose to leave the first points zero on the idea that we don’t know their doubling time...

Answer (score 0):

Probably could end up looking something like this.

```
ACCURACY = 0

cases = [197, 218, 256, 328, 413,525, 646, 646, 777,
          1159, 1838, 2417, 3240, 4257, 4955, 4955,
          5752, 6620, 7738, 8966, 10402]
doubling = []

for t in range(len(cases)):
    found = False
    for t_2 in range(t):
        if cases[t_2] - (cases[t] // 2) > ACCURACY:
            doubling.append(t - t_2)
            found = True
            break

    # Append nothing if value not found
    if not found:
        doubling.append(None)
```